# Busybox initramfs again and again

Tags: boot, initramfs, busybox

I have ubuntu 16.04 installed.. whenever I boot the system and try to run ubuntu, busy box pops up. I do a manual check ---fsck -yf /dev/sda12--- and then reboot.. now the ubuntu boots properly but then after few minutes i am not able to save/write anything on ubuntu(says the the disk is read only) nor can i open my other partitions which i was able to access few minutes ago. I again restart my system and the same busybox appears. The cycle goes on and on. What should i do.. is my hard drive completely corrupted?

Comment: See my recent answer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019790/windows-10-corrupts-ubuntu-18-04-partitions/1020722#1020722 and see if it applies to your situation.

Comment: I have already done that.. also i did not install any windows driver

Comment: What kind of primary disk do you use... hard disk or SSD? Open the `Disks` application and look at the SMART data to see if you're having a hardware problem. Do any of your other installed OS's have a problem also?

Comment: A mistake from my side.. i did not run the command in recovery mode but in the normal mode... everything works perfectly now... thanks for the help, you are great :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets first check your file system for errors.

For Ubuntu 17.10 or older...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose <kbd>Advanced Options</kbd>
- choose <kbd>Recovery mode</kbd>
- choose <kbd>Root access</kbd>
- at the `#` prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

For Ubuntu 18.04 or newer... (or if the above steps don't work for you)...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Thank you for share the solution it really helped me lots. Suddenly some directory was showing mount system/file system is read-only. I rebooted and it has fallen into `initramfs`

Comment: This helped a lot after I shrank my root Ubuntu 18.04 partition

Answer (score 4):

first, run the command

```
blkid
```

then check the number of partitions

it will look like

/dev/numve2: UUID="kksgasjhgdjh36876" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="bdmdmd7-iuuyuy-89jlh"
/dev/numve4: UUID="kksgasjhgdjh36876" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="bjjlo-iuuyuy-89jlh"

now just run the command for all partitions:

```
fsck /dev/numve2 -y
fsck /dev/numve4 -y
```

after done for all partition just run :

```
reboot
```

and choose **ubuntu**
it will work!!

Comment: this worked for my Ubuntu 18.04