# Ubuntu freezes after seconds of booting

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, ubuntu-drivers

I am unable to use Ubuntu 17.1. I have been using it for a long time now. Suddenly after booting one day, it froze and didn't respond anymore. The gui, the mouse, keyboard, nothing responds.  I am unable to do anything. I am not familiar with the structure of the operating system so any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Try run usb live Ubuntu, if it won't start it's a hardware issue.

Comment: How could it be hardware issue? I have been using it for so long. Windows 10 runs fine. (I have dual boot)

Comment: What if it works with live usb? How am I supposed to keep my system from freezing. I have many important software there. I must not delete the system.

Comment: See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020872/busybox-initramfs-again-and-again/1021087#1021087 and see if that helps. Report back. Start comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema tried it and still the same issue. Kinda feeling hopeless right now.

Comment: You say it froze one day after 'booting'. So, can you reach GRUB now, and boot into Ubuntu from there before it freezes? If not, how are you booting into Windows?  Did it freeze after you were logged in and working, or before?

Comment: No. I meant in a sudden day, I booted it and it froze a few seconds after logging in. Tried fsck and cleaning in recovery but nothing. I don't understand what happened.

Comment: I'm still none the wiser. What is happening now? How far are you getting when you try to boot into Ubuntu? Can you reach and use GRUB without the freezing? Eg how do you boot into Windows?

Comment: It sounds like you CAN get to GRUB, and you CAN run `fsck`, so we know that the keyboard is working and the disk checked OK. Were there any errors during the `fsck`? If you reboot, do you ever get to the login screen, where you type in your password? Do you ever get to your desktop, whether the keyboard/mouse work or not? Do you see the clock updating at the top/center of your screen?

Comment: Yes. I access GRUB. The system boots fine. I log in. The desktop shows up and after a couple of seconds everything freezes. Nothing works, neither hardware (keyboard, touchpad, mouse) nor software. I have to press the shutdown button in order to get out of there.

Comment: Like everything else in this world computer hardware and electronics are subject to [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy) and thus degradation over time. Some parts in computer are particularly affected (e. g. air fans, storage drives, memory modules and some types of capacitors and transistors). Computers can just cease to function partly or completely overnight in “normal” everyday environments and even in ideal environments. It's rare enough that manufacturers cover it under warranties for some time after purchase but it does happen.

Comment: @Foerster It's true. My laptop is 6 years old, but it is working fine. Replacing my HDD with a SAMSUNG SSD was the best decision I made for that laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many efforts I managed to fix this. The problem was at the kernel. 
I entered recovery mode.
Opened root terminal.
And updated my kernel version. 
After that everything works fine.