# Stuck at initramfs after system update(ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: boot, kernel, mount

Error

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/920903aa-762f-40d2-8126-87f4b0e6f975 does not exist. Dropping to a shell

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a lost of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```

I Tried

```
(initramfs)blkid
: empty result
```

```
(initramfs)cat /etc/fstab 
also showing empty
```

```
reboot is also not working
```

I tried different solution which are already available on internet but nothing is worked

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20. It needs to be 20.04 or 20.10 which is it?

Comment: i have updated question : ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the same happened to me installing Ubuntu for the first time (dual booting with windowz) ...
I have not resolved it. I reinstalled openSUSE which worked as normal with the correct grub list appearing, but because I really want Ubuntu.
I tried again and again only a ">grub" appears and the the initramfs. This solution on askubuntu worked for me to repair the file system: [Busybox initramfs again and again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020872/busybox-initramfs-again-and-again)

But still at startup only grub> prompt.
I then typed 'exit' and windows boot manager appears with options, I chose the 2nd and the ubuntu grub menu appeared and I could start. It's not handy but a workaround till I find the solution.

Comment: I have ubuntu live usb I am able to boot using live usb but the partion is not showing in the gparted and disk utility (SSD)