# Ubuntu 18.04 won't start w/ dual-boot Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04, nvidia, uninstall

Preface: I have search many posts already to try and answer my issue, but haven't found any that help w/ my specific issue. Searched posts found in post-script section.

I have a Lenovo Y700 with nvidia geforce gtx and Windows 10 preloaded. I installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS as dual-boot. Everything was working fine for a bit until Ubuntu would not start. Now, I choose ubuntu from the GRUB Startup and get (sorry for image quality, it's a photo of the screen since I can't screenshot):
[Ubuntu start-up screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuBIh.jpg)

The start-up screen stays like this indefinitely. So, what I'd like to do is uninstall Ubuntu and re-install.

Since I cannot work inside Ubuntu everything needs to be done in Windows, but I don't have the Windows Installation CD.

I don't want to delete important partitions and can't use GParted. Here is my Disk Management:
[Disk Management window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzUGV.png)

So, please advise in which partitions to delete, and any necessary steps to uninstall Ubuntu, then re-install Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. Thanks in advance!

P.S.
I've tried this: [Windows 10 corrupts Ubuntu 18.04 partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019790/windows-10-corrupts-ubuntu-18-04-partitions), and get e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
I've reviewed this: [How can I find out which partition Ubuntu is installed on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527863/how-can-i-find-out-which-partition-ubuntu-is-installed-on)
I've reviewed this: [Reinstalling Ubuntu with a dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042746/reinstalling-ubuntu-with-a-dual-boot). Here I followed the steps to Create a bootable USB stick on Windows and tried booting Ubuntu from USB. This gets me to the same *Ubuntu start-up screen* image from above.

Comment: Are you using nomodeset boot parameter  since you have nVidia? Or try to boot with recovery mode? http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it  This user installed on same system. http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2016/05/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-10.html

Comment: Thanks @oldfred. I changed boot parameter to nomodeset and followed directions for boot repair, but no luck. I'll work through the other link and report back.

Comment: Hold up a few secnds... before ripping through deleting partitions and reinstalling Ubuntu, let's a check few things first. Can you boot to Recover Mode from the GRUB Advanced Options menu? Have you run a fsck on your Ubuntu partition? I'll post a quickie answer on how to do that...

Comment: Have you installed a Windows driver that allows you to r/w to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions? I see your Ubuntu partition labeled as E:.

Comment: @heynnema I had previously installed ubuntu from USB, which created the partitions. The E: drive is a removable USB with the new Ubuntu I want to reinstall with.

Comment: If E: is a bootable Ubuntu Live USB, then run gparted from there, and show me a screenshot, then I can properly advise you. Windows Disk Management is only for managing ntfs partitions. gparted is used for managing Linux ext4 partitions. Your Disk Management screenshot doesn't show me where your current defective Ubuntu is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer...

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: I went through the steps above. /dev/sda4 is Linux Swap, and /dev/sda5 & /dev/sda6 are Linux Filesystem. 

I ran `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda6` through GRUB Advanced Options with root and says it's mounted but `e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.`. I then rebooted and screen is black with blinking curser.

Also, in root after running `sudo fdisk -l` i get the message **Partition 1 does not start on physical boundary.**

Comment: @zhl on 18.04, you need to follow my instructions exactly... which means that you can't do this from GRUB Advanced Options, you have to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. You also have a partitioning problem with partition 1.

Comment: My mistake. I booted from USB, ran fsck commands with no errors, and rebooted. Boot-up stops at [ OK ] Started Hostname Service.

Comment: @zhl Do you boot normally with a wired, or wireless connection? If wired, will it boot if you leave the ethernet cable unplugged? Also, once booted to the Ubuntu Live USB, and select install, it should find the old Ubuntu, and ask if you want to reinstall. You should be able to select that, and uncheck the "format partition" checkbox, and that'll keep your home folder intact, hopefully. Of course, you could always backup some important files first, just in case..

Comment: @zhl status please...

Comment: I ended up deleting Ubuntu partitions within Windows Disk Management and reinstalled Ubuntu from USB. I followed <https://www.pcsuggest.com/uninstall-ubuntu-dual-boot-windows/> for uninstall, and <http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2016/05/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-10.html> for reinstall. All is working well now.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all suggestions from @oldfred & @heynnema I ended up deleting Ubuntu partitions within Windows Disk Management and reinstalled Ubuntu from USB. I followed https://www.pcsuggest.com/uninstall-ubuntu-dual-boot-windows/ for uninstall, and http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2016/05/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-10.html for reinstall. All is working well now. Many thanks to @oldfred & @heynnema for your help!